# My Strapi (deployed on Heroku) deletes all it's data, even administrator

Tags: vue.js, heroku, strapi

Im creating a vue app and Im trying to fetch data from this Strapi api to my VueJs app, but everything on Strapi gets deleted after a few hours. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

So everytime Heroku cycles it's Dynos, your data will disappear. That is because Heroku doesn't allow for the file system to have changes made. However, you can use their mLab add on to use MongoDB or host your database on MongoDB Atlas (which is what I use). Then for media, you will need to use an external provider like AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing kept happening to me... I had to switch to Mongo DB. You can also use Cloudinary for media

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try switching to Mongo DB

Comment: I switched to Mongo DB, can u show me how to add Cloudinary also. I can find a working documentation or anything about it?